# Azure Data Catalog intefacing with Azure SQL Server metadata - not picking up Azure SQL Server metadata when publishing data source

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-catalog

ive set some extended properties the MS_description field of several views and tables. I've tried publishing my data source twice now and I can't see any of the descriptions in the description field for that table or view within ADC

How can I synch ADC with my Azure SQL Server extended properties?

Answer (score 0):

Currently metadata for Azure SQL Databases don't flow automatically into Azure Data Catalog. I've just finished building an interface to connect the two together using the (very poorly documented) API's